# Flatten large complex JSON data after reading into spark dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm running into issues when trying to flatten JSON data into a tabular view. Here's some data to get an idea of the schema:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "ID": "XYZ_12345",
        "Name": "Example Product #1 w/symbols",
        "Product Properties": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-10"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Active_Item",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "Product Pricing": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-11"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Latest_Price",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "Product Parent": [
            {
                "Num": "123",
                "Description": "Descriptive text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "ABC_54321",
        "Name": "Example Product 2",
        "Product Properties": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-02"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Active_Item",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "Product Pricing": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-13"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Latest_Price",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "Product Parent": [
            {
                "Num": "543",
                "Description": "Detailed text"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm first reading the file into a spark data frame

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json('path/to/file.json')
```

Now I need to flatten the data. I've looked through creating a manual schema as well as a few flattening functions. The largest issue I'm having is the "attribute" and "value" elements. The value of "attribute" needs to be the column name, and the value of "value" needs to be the row data. And yes, certain "attribute" values are the same such as Created_Date. But then other portions of the data, like "Num" and "Description" are the actual column requirements, and then the value of those elements would be the row data.

At this time I don't need all the data. So I would accept something that does flatten out everything, or something where I choose the elements I need. Taking the example data and returning something similar to the following would be fine:

| ID | Product Created Date | Active_Item | Parent Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ_12345 | 2021-01-10 | Y | 123 |
| ABC_54321 | 2024-01-02 | Y | 543 |

Any thoughts to get me headed in the right direction?

***UPDATED QUESTION***
After working further on this, I really just need one last bit of help. So here's a modified question. Given the simplified JSON below, how can I return whether each product is Active? Notice the index of the Active_Item struct is not necessarily the same in each Product Properties array.

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "Name": "Product #1",
        "Product Properties": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-10"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Active_Item",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Product 2",
        "Product Properties": [
            {
                "attribute": "Created_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-02"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Modified_Date",
                "value": "2024-01-03"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "Active_Item",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an SQL based solution.

First, lets create a temp view so we can work with SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("products_json")
```

Now, we can use SQL functions to extract the columns from the JSON construct:

Explode - to change the products array to rows

```
%sql
select 
  products.ID,
  products.`Product Pricing`[0].value as `Product Created Date`,
  products.`Product Properties`[1].value as Active_Item,
  products.`Product Parent`[0].Num as `Parent Num`
from (
select explode(products) as products
from products_json) i
```

Results:

[image]

Please note that it's based on the attributes index in the arrays, so it will work if your file schema doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Chen. I was getting a couple odd values returned when running this solution against my real data. To troubleshoot, I changed the select statements from .value to .attribute. Unfortunately I get a few different results in a few of the columns. This tells me the index method doesn't work for me since the schema isn't consistent for each product within the products array